# Why Robo tests gets marked as passed so quickly?

Tags: android, firebase-test-lab

TL;DR

The app has tons of flows, but sometimes runs get passed faster than 2 mins...

---

Is there any way to keep it running until the [timeout period](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--timeout) (e.g. 1hr) is almost consumed? Attached a screenshot for a quick termination e.g.

[image: Fast passed e.g.]

Although the app is very big with tons of flows, sometimes runs get passed after 2min, 5mins but what is the critieria which decides that the running robo test should terminate now with a passed result? any idea what makes the recorded graph decides to go to this node? n.b. I assumed it's the terminal node

[image: terminated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why Robo tests get marked as passed so quickly?

It turns out that due to having a varying b.e. responses, the app journey gets changed. If there're 3 disconnected components (as in gif), what happens is sth like the app can start in any of the 3 flows resembling the 3 components. Which implies how long the journey will be

> Is there any way to keep it running until the timeout period (e.g. 1hr) is almost consumed

Guiding the robo tests as explained [here](https://youtu.be/HLLX7rOXGfw?t=122) is a promising way to let journey bigger by following some sequence of actions which make the graph bigger

> What is the criteria which decides that the running robo test should terminate now with a passed result?

Robo tests are simply applying [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) on the app (as in gif). Where the *graph* *nodes* are represented by screens, e.g. onboarding screen, and *edges* are represented by actions, e.g. click on next button

[image: Recursive flood fill with 4 directions]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is always more or less the same time duration ...while the only difference may be the test's position in the queue (you're not the only user there, which is why it may appear as if the duration would vary). And that `TerminatedActivity-33` only confirms that the `Activity` under test had been successfully terminated ...which is "The End" of the story.
For reasons of efficiency, the test will terminate as soon as possible - the timeout value can only be reached when it's stuck.

That the queue may also run in parallel might be another possible cause; while then, even if the real-time duration would indeed vary, the processing time (CPU shares) would still be about the same. Disclaimer: I have no clue how it internally works, just tried to apply some common sense.

Comment: Thanks for approaching the question! I believe the time duration is not including the queuing time. On checking different robo runs, the longer the time taken, the bigger the crawl graph and the number of visited activities. But still the question is open when the robo decides this the last activity